# Inserting current date into mysql database using android studio?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to insert current date into mysql database using android studio. And I am using volley library for insertion. Need hints only, not in detail. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you take a look at the [library training center](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)?

Comment: yes, I have tried inserting date but it wasn't working. Can you provide me little help?

Comment: I can't help withou seeing the code snipped. Put in your question what's not working, so I can help you.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> You should try this one for getting current date:




 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    String todate= dateFormat.format(currentdate());

  String  finalto = todate.toString(); //here you get current date
    private Date currentdate() {
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            return cal.getTime();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Harshal Deshmukh.

Comment: wc sir..........